# How to fix "Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx64.so' for target: Linux, 64-bit"

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to use the headless LibGDX for unit testing, but when I run the test I get this error:

> Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx64.so' for target: Linux, 64-bit

I read [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/1127) that I need to add `gdx-natives.jar`. Is this correct, and where can I find this file?

Also, where in my project should I add the file?

Comment: Here to download: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/

Here for explanations: http://agmprojects.com/blog/setting-up-a-basic-libgdx-project

Comment: I guess I should have mention I am using IntelliJ IDEA and the LibGDX-setup-ui. I saw that tutorial before, but since it is based on a custom Eclipse project, I can't seem to get it to work in my project.

Comment: May be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the Maven support for libgdx is incomplete (or deprecated)? I'm getting this error when trying to run a small libgdx app that was built using Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer on [this BitBucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/TomGrill/libgdx-testing-sample/src). The README gives a nice explanation of how to implement this using Gradle.

Basically, you just add [GdxTestRunner.java](https://bitbucket.org/TomGrill/libgdx-testing-sample/src/df874d51ce9e19cc3b6515b8d71062bced026b33/core/src/com/libgdxtesting/GdxTestRunner.java?at=master) from that repo, and then add a `@RunWith` to each of your test files:

```
@RunWith(GdxTestRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    ...
}
```

Then in your root level `build.gradle` file, add something like this to your `core` dependencies:

```
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```

Obviously the `box2d` and `bullet` dependencies are only necessary if you are using those libraries.

---

On the BitBucket repo README, the example includes both

```
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
```

and

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
```

I don't think it is necessary to include this for `compile`, and if I correctly understand how Gradle works, it will actually slow down your build.

Comment: The linked repository has been deleted and is now at https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-testing.